# Address a specific soundtrack in a video in iOS

Tags: ios, video

Does anyone know, if iOS has the opportunity to address a specific soundtrack in a video? I have a .mov file that contains two soundtracks (different languages). I have looked through the MPMoviePlayer and AVPlayer classes, but I can´t find anything-

Comment: What do you mean with address a specific sound track?

Answer (score 0):

With AVFoundation, [AVAssetTrack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what your looking for.